# Add a label/text (ideally positioned above a countdown timer) using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I added the label tag which I thought would solve the problem but when I run the project nothing happens so I kinda at my wit's end also I doing this project is that is important at all to the problem and the ide is Thonny.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import time
import datetime

global endTime 

def quit(*args):
    root.destroy()
    
def show_time():
    # Get the time remaining until the event
    remainder = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
    # remove the microseconds part
    remainder = remainder - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)
    # Show the time left
    txt.set(remainder)
    # Trigger the countdown after 1000ms
    root.after(1000, show_time)

# Use tkinter lib for showing the clock
root = Tk()
label(root,text="timer", bg="black", fg=Fdf800")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("x", quit)
root.after(1000, show_time)

# Set the end date and time for the countdown
endTime = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 9, 0, 0)

fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=60, weight='bold')
txt = StringVar()
lbl = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=txt, font=fnt, foreground="green", background="black")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place a `tk.Label()` using `.pack()`, `.grid()` or `.place()`.
For your use case, it seems `.pack()` would be suitable; you will want to use this for all your widgets for consistency, e.g.

```
label = Label(root,text="timer", bg="black")
label.pack()
```

Full (modified) code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import time
import datetime


def quit(*args):
    root.destroy()
    
def show_time():
    # Get the time remaining until the event
    remainder = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
    # remove the microseconds part
    remainder = remainder - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)
    # Show the time left
    txt.set(remainder)
    # Trigger the countdown after 1000ms
    root.after(1000, show_time)

# Use tkinter lib for showing the clock
root = Tk()
label = Label(root,text="timer", bg="black", fg="red")
label.pack()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("x", quit)
root.after(1000, show_time)

# Set the end date and time for the countdown
endTime = datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 19, 9, 0, 0)

fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=60, weight='bold')
txt = StringVar()
lbl = ttk.Label(root, textvariable=txt, font=fnt, foreground="green", background="black")
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Which produces the result:
[image]