# how to stop tkinter timer function when i press button one more times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i'd tried to use root.after_cancel(AFTER), but i dont know how.

````
    root.after_cancel(AFTER) 
AFTER = None
def countdown(count,time,name):
    global AFTER
    time['text'] =name,":",datetime.fromtimestamp(count).strftime("%M:%S")
    if count > 0 :
        AFTER = root.after(1000, countdown, count-1,time,name)
    elif count == 0 :
        time['text'] = f"Возрожден:{name}"```
````

Comment: You say you don't know how to use `after_cancel` but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code (other than it's not complete and has indentation problems). Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: its not update timer, only impose on yourself twice, if u have telegram or same messager i can send u a video how it bag, if u can help me

Comment: sorry , my english is bad, but i trying to speek :(

Comment: I am curious if my answer is what you are looking after - let me know ... and if it is ... accept it as answer :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess what actually you are after, but ... below working code which outputs to stdout and is able to start/stop/restart the countdown with pressing the `[Countdown]` button. The 'trick' is to run the timer all the time checking a value of a global variable, where pressing the button sets the value of that variable depending on what value it currently has. The way the code works appears to be an answer to both of your questions (**1. how to stop and 2. how to reset the countdown by pressing the same button with which the countdown was started**).

```
def countdown():
    global countdownValue
    if countdownValue > 0 :
        print(' countdown: ', countdownValue)
        countdownValue -= 1
    if countdownValue == 0 :
        countdownValue = -1
        print(f"\n  Возрожден:  {name} :) ")
    root.after(1000, countdown)

def startStopCountdown():
    global countdownValue
    if countdownValue > 0:
        print('stopCountdown')
        countdownValue = -1
    else: 
        print('startCountdown')
        countdownValue = 10

import tkinter as tk
countdownValue = -1
name           = 'Возро'
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("3,2,1,...")
btn = tk.Button( root, text="Countdown", font=('',20), 
                 command=startStopCountdown)
btn.grid()
countdown()
root.mainloop()
```

By the way: in the context of your question following comes to my mind as maybe helpful in the context of your question [Add a label/text (ideally positioned above a countdown timer) using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153081/add-a-label-text-ideally-positioned-above-a-countdown-timer-using-tkinter) .